# Get SID of current user

Tags: c#, .net-core

How do I extract the SID of the current logged in user in a web application?

User.Identity.Name gives me the user account:

[image]

If I hover over User.Identity I can see the SID but I can't figure out how to extract it?

[image]

Comment: `((WindowsIdentity)User.Identity).Owner`?

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thanks a lot @GSerg!